Compound interest with Euler's number
$e^r = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{r}{n})^n \approx 2.171828^r$

p initial investment amount
r interest rate per year
t time in years
n number of segments in which the interest will be given per year  ( the received interest will be $P.\frac{r}{n}$ , n times in every year ).

So now:

Total $= P.(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt}$
For $\lim_{n\to ∞} P.(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt} ≈ P.e^{rt} $
Total $= P.e^{rt}$

What isn't clear for me is:

How can we reach $e^r$ from $(1+\frac{r}{n})^n$
How $ P.e^{rt}$ is still considered as the total after t years in case of $n = 1$ , since we reached $ P.e^{rt}$ by having n→∞. To be more clear how is $\lim_{n\to∞}⁡ P.(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt} $ is considered the same as $P.(1+r)^{nt}$


Welcome to Math StackExchange. Please use MathJax to properly typeset your equations.

This is how I understand your question: to prove that $(1+\frac{r}{n})^n = e^r$. Is this what you want to ask?

@Tejasparashar yes this is one of the two points those I was asking about

@DuongNgo Thanks for letting me know about MathJax. I tried to format the equations on microsoft word and past it here, but it didn't work.
